# Makefile and symbolic links

Tags: linux, makefile, ln

I'm experiencing a strange problem with a makefile. I simply want to set a symbolic link in the makefile but get an error message on one machine (Linux 2.6.18-238.12.1.el5)

```
make: execvp: ln: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

It works perfectly fine on my MacBook. It also works fine if I execute the same command in the shell. What could go wrong? Are there any environment variables important for `ln`?

Comment: Are you sure that what you do on the command line is what your rule tries to do? Could you show us the rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `execvp` in the error message is the key, I think.  I believe it is saying there are too many levels of symbolic links *while trying to locate the ln command itself*.

Example:

```
all:
    ln -nsf /tmp/foo /tmp/foo
    /tmp/foo/ln x y
```

Running "make" with this Makefile errors out with:

```
make: execvp: /tmp/foo/ln: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

So, how is your Makefile invoking `ln`, exactly?  What is in your `PATH` etc.?

[update]

I bet the Makefile is messing up your PATH.  Here is a Makefile that reproduces your exact error message:

```
PATH=/tmp/foo

all:
    /bin/ln -nsf /tmp/foo /tmp/foo
    ln x y
```

Comment: I think you're right. When I call /bin/ln it works. Now I just need to figure out where it's messing up the paths. Thanks!