# Bin Utils are not compiling

Tags: gcc, makefile

I am trying to compile binutils-2.18 using gcc (GCC) 4.9.1 20140903 but it is not compiling and showing the following error.

```
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating bfd-in3.h
config.status: creating po/Makefile.in
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
config.status: executing default-1 commands
config.status: executing bfd_stdint.h commands
config.status: executing default commands
make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/binutils-build/libiberty'
if [ x"" != x ] && [ ! -d pic ]; then \
  mkdir pic; \
else true; fi
touch stamp-picdir
make[2]: execvp: touch: Too many levels of symbolic links
Makefile:402: recipe for target 'stamp-picdir' failed
make[2]: *** [stamp-picdir] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/binutils-build/libiberty'
Makefile:8263: recipe for target 'all-libiberty' failed
make[1]: *** [all-libiberty] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/binutils-build'
Makefile:676: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Kindly Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems more likely you'd get an answer on `#gcc` on `irc.freenode.org` or via some [googling](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/pipermail/lfs-support/2009-August/036281.html) or [searching this site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027740/makefile-and-symbolic-links)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer comes a bit late, but I had the same problem when I tried to build binutils 2.9 with gcc 4.9.2 and the solution for me was another version of binutils.

binutils-2.24 worked fine with gcc 4.9.2